# Where can I find management scripts for IIS 6.0?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I'm running Windows 2003 R2 and IIS 6.0 with web applications written in ASP.NET.

I am looking for good samples of scripts (.bat, .cmd, .VBS, or powershell) to allow me to:

For websites:

- Create website
- Verify if website exists
- Delete website

For virtual directories:

- Create virtual directory
- Verify if virtual directory exists
- Delete virtual directory

For application pools:

- Create application pool
- Verify if application pool exists
- Delete application pool
- Assigning website to application pool

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question the other day:

> [Automated creation of IIS websites (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850225/automated-creation-of-iis-websites/1856590#1856590)

You can use the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace directly from PowerShell as well as C#.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you need can be found in the system32 directory. Look for the files:

```
iis*.vbs
```

for start run:

```
cscript c:\WINDOWS\system32\iisweb.vbs /?
```

To create application pool, look at [David Wang post](http://blogs.msdn.com/david.wang/archive/2007/12/12/howto-create-custom-application-pool-by-commandline.aspx).